# Convolution of two characteristic functions strictly positive

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Given Borel measurable $A, B$ such that the Lebesgue measure of each is non-zero, I want to show that the convolution of their characteristic functions $\chi_A * \chi_B (x)$ is not zero everywhere.

I think this is very basic to see (and I understand it intuitively), but I can't seem to show it formally!

Comment: I guess the title here is wrong: should be "strictly positive somewhere"

Answer (score 2):

Use Fubini’s theorem to show the integral of the convolution is nonzero.